# Regex Parse In any order at most once

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a Date parser (Tenor parser exactly) where I have to extract dates set as a sum of number of days, weeks, months and years.

This would look like 1d1y or 100m2w or 1y1d1m1w.

I've built a custom parser but I'm looking for a cleaner solution using Regex. I have to check that it contains at most once of each date characters (d, w, m and y) and separated with an integer.

```
^(?<ValueDay>[0-9]+(d))?(?<ValueWeek>[0-9]+(w))?(?<ValueMonth>[0-9]+(m))?(?<ValueYear>[0-9]+(y))?$
```

The problem I have is that it could happen in any order (1d1w works as well as 1w1d). I tried to use the positive lookahead (?=) as follow but it doesn't match all the criterias.

```
^(?=.*(?<ValueDay>[0-9]+(d)))?(?=.*(?<ValueWeek>[0-9]+(w)))?(?=.*(?<ValueMonth>[0-9]+(m)))?(?=.*(?<ValueYear>[0-9]+(y)))?.*$
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Use three separate `Regex.Match` calls, it is the easiest way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there are 24 permutations, did you mean 24 regex calls?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek There are only 4 values to extract, hence, only 4: 1) day - `@"(\d+)d"`, 1) week - `@"(\d+)w"`, 1) month - `@"(\d+)m"`, 1) year - `@"(\d+)y"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but it does not test validity of the input at all. Refusing to parse nonsense is very desirable and even OP requires that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each group must occur zero or one time, you can use the following:

```
^
 (
  (?(y)(?!)|(?<y>\d+)y)
  |
  (?(m)(?!)|(?<m>\d+)m)
  |
  (?(w)(?!)|(?<w>\d+)w)
  |
  (?(d)(?!)|(?<d>\d+)d)
 )+
$
```

For each letter, it checks whether the group with that letter as a name has a match already. If so, it fails and moves onto the next letter. If not, it tries to capture digits followed by that letter, into the group with that letter as the name.

---

Previous answer - everything-happens-exactly-once version:

```
^((?<y>\d+)y|(?<m>\d+)m|(?<w>\d+)w|(?<d>\d+)d){4}$(?<-y>)(?<-m>)(?<-w>)(?<-d>)
```

This checks for:

- start of input
- one of `y`, `m`, `w` or `d`

  - four times (= number of groups)
- end of input
- *that at least one `y` was matched*
- *that at least one `m` was matched*
- *that at least one `w` was matched*
- *that at least one `d` was matched*

Comment: You are not actually checking anything here, you just pop the capture stack with `(?<-a>)`. You would need a conditional construct to actually check if the capture stack is empty. Anyway, it won't work like this as the number of parts is variable.

Comment: By popping, you are checking that one existed. By counting the number of parts in, you do not need to check  each stack is empty afterwards. If you have a variable number of parts, you can trivially construct a regex with a different number in the braces.

Comment: I require to check if the patterns `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` happen zero or one time, so I'll need to dynamically change the pattern for each record I'm parsing. And I'll need to parse and check the data before applying the regex.

Comment: @user3627975 I've added a version for zero-or-one matches of each group. You should be able to use whether the regex as a whole succeeds as your parse/check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(\d+)([wydm])(?!.*\2)"
                + @"(?:(\d+)([wydm])(?!.*\4))?"
                + @"(?:(\d+)([wydm])(?!.*\6))?"
                + @"(?:(\d+)([wydm]))?$");
```

This should work. It matches `\d+[wydm]` at least once and at most four times. Above that, when a character `[wydm]` is matched, it looks ahead and the same character shall not occur in the text the second time. Now you can get the values from groups:

```
int GetValue(Match m)
{
    int GetGroupValue(Group numberGroup, Group characterGroup)
    {
        if (!numberGroup.Success) { return 0; }
        int number = int.Parse(numberGroup.Value);
        switch (characterGroup.Value)
        {
            case "d": return number;
            case "w": return 7 * number;
            case "m": return 31 * number;
            case "y": return 365 * number;
            default: throw new NotSupportedException(characterGroup.Value + " is not supported");
        }
    }

    return GetGroupValue(m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2])
         + GetGroupValue(m.Groups[3], m.Groups[4])
         + GetGroupValue(m.Groups[5], m.Groups[6])
         + GetGroupValue(m.Groups[7], m.Groups[8]);
}
```

Here are some tests to verify the corectness:

```
var tests = new (string s, bool isOk, int desiredValue)[] {
    ("15y", true, 15*365),
    ("1000w", true, 1000*7),
    ("10000d", true, 10000),
    ("100000m", true, 100000*31),
    ("15y8y", false, 0),
    ("", false, 0),
    ("7y9w12m2d", true, 7*365 + 9*7 + 12*31 + 2),
    ("7d9m12w2y", true, 7 + 9*31 + 12*7 + 2*365),
    ("7y9w12m2dd", false, 0),
    ("7y9w12m2y", false, 0),
    ("7y9w12m2x", false, 0),
    ("-5y", false, 0),
    ("1", false, 0),
    ("y2", false, 0),
    ("yd", false, 0),
    ("7y1", false, 0),
    ("m5d", false, 0)
    };

foreach (var test in tests)
{
    Match m = r.Match(test.s);
    if (m.Success != test.isOk)
    {
        throw new Exception("Test failed for " + test.Item1);
    }
    if (GetValue(m) != test.desiredValue)
    {
        throw new Exception("Test failed for " + test.Item1);
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("All " + tests.Count() + " tests passed");
```

Comment: Thanks it does work perfectly for verification of the input. I can later split the valid input with `^{d|w|m|y}$` and calculate the number of days. Just wondering if there is a way to parse on the same regex call cause I can't use the `Match.Groups` with this solution.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Regex groups are way to get parsed parts of the regex. How do you expect to read regex groups without using regex groups?

Comment: I mean that with this solution we could create up to 4 groups but we don't know what's inside right? Like I can't explicitly name it like above `?<ValueWeek>` or using the index, for example and directly calculate the sum of days.

Comment: I intentionally tried to avoid that as I am not sure what are you trying to calculate. But as you struggle with that I updated the answer to better show you how to deal with it.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help!